# Handling call back in jQuery treetable

Tags: jquery, callback, tree

I am new to Javascript and jQuery world. I am trying to display a tree table using the jQueryTree table at the link below.

http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/

it provides a few call back functions

- `onInitialized` Callback function fired when the tree has been initialized.
- `onNodeCollapse` Callback function fired when a branch is collapsed.
- `onNodeExpand` Callback function fired when a branch is expanded.
- `onNodeInitialized` Callback function fired when a node has been initialized.

I understand what the call back functions are. I am having trouble trying to code for in Javascript.

Can any help me understand how I can handle these call back functions. I am trying to get the id of the selected node.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following snippet (to save a collapse-state of a row to a database):

```
    holder.treetable({
        onNodeCollapse: function(){
            var node = this;
            var rowobject = node.row;
            // do some stuff with the row or ...
        },
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the tree plugin:

```
$("#example-advanced").treetable({ expandable: true });
```

And add a mouse down event on tr to get the id of the node, id is stored in `data-tt-id` data attribute.

```
 $("#example-advanced tbody").on("mousedown", "tr", function() {
      alert(this.getAttribute('data-tt-id')); 
 });
```

Comment: i tried that but with every click on the treenode to expand this call gets fired, I have this tree in an frame on the left hand side. Based on the selection I need to load right hand side data in a frame. But even before i selected the node expanding itself was causing the even to fire

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected node you don't need a callback function. Just get the element with "selected" class (that's the class added by the plugin when you select something - at least that's what I've noticed in my 10 seconds research on the plugin).

Try this: `$(".selected").attr("id");`

Or do you need to fire an event on select? That's a different business.

Comment: how do i handle the callback funtions already provided as described in my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there a few hoops to jump through

try

```
$("#jTable").treetable({ expandable: true, onNodeExpand: nodeExpand});

$("#jTable tbody").on("mousedown", "tr", function() {

$(".selected").not(this).removeClass("selected");
$(this).toggleClass("selected");    

if(!$(this).is(".expanded")) {
       $("#jTable").treetable("expandNode", $(this).data("ttId"));
    }
});
```

and then write the `nodeExapnd` function as referenced in the treetable properties

```
function nodeExpand () {
    alert ("expanded");
    alert ( $(".selected").data("ttId"));
}
```